# Hosting WPF UserControl in a transparent Windows.Form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, transparency, elementhost

I need to insert my WPF `USerControl` into a `Windows.Form`. This is my control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Background="Transparent">

    <InkCanvas x:Name="Ink" Background="Transparent" />

</UserControl>
```

To host this control I use an `ElementHost` object as the only one control of my Form. I need to have the possibility to do the following: when I set the opacity of the form to 0, in order to make it invisible, I need to continue to have the opacity of all the `Children` and `Strokes` of My `InkCanvas` to 1 (so I can see them).

I tried using the `TransparencyKey` property, but it seems it doesn't work with the `ElementHost`. How can I solve this problem, and how can I set a different opacity between my Form and my UserControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK  that's not possible  as WPF use Subpixel alpha rendering   which is not available  with winform for example

Hope this  help

Comment: take a look at this article it may be a starting point  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/changov/archive/2009/01/19/webbrowser-control-on-transparent-wpf-window.aspx

Comment: but you  can immagine  a work around like that one  ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to host a WPF control that behaves transparently on Win Forms, follow these steps

- Create WPF usercontrol control and set background ="transparent".
- Create Win User Control with no controls on it and write following
  code on its back end:

  ```
  public WinControl()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
  }
  protected override CreateParams CreateParams
  {
      get
      {
          CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;

          cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020;
          return cp;
      }
  }
  ```
- Now place WPF usercontrol on Win user control and dock wpfusercontrol
  to its parent(win user control).
- Now drag win user control on the |Win Form and dock win user control
  to its parent(Form)

And you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use Microsoft.Ink.dll to create your own WinForms-based UserControl that supports handwriting recognition if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please, can you link any reference?

Comment: Sure.  I hosted a small example using the Microsoft.Ink DLL, go to http://nmctl.codeplex.com, go to the source tree and download the InkSample directory.  

The Ink dll SHOULD be found in C:\Windows\assembly ... FYI there are quite a few libraries that Visual Studio doesn't automatically find that are available in that directory and also in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET) ...